# How to do canary releases and dynamic routing with Netflix Zuul?

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, netflix-zuul, canary-deployment, dynamic-routing

We faced with the problem that we need to do such thing as dynamic routing and canary releases. So, for example, we deploy microservice `microservice-1`. Then, when someone finished a big feature we want to deploy it as a microservice `microservice-1.1`.

#### Question

Is it possible to dynamically reroute requests using information, for example, from Headers, and route to the microservice version `microservice-1.1` instead on `microservice-1`?

For example, someone needs this feature and he will modify/add specific Header and for all requests, he will use new `microservice-1.1`. And if that Header is missing then the current microservice-1 version should be used.

For service discovery, I am using Eureka. Right now I am looking at [linkerd](https://linkerd.io/) but there is no support for Eureka and I am working on it right now. Of course, if it is possible to do it using Zuul that would be great. Please advise where to look at.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure about Netflix Zuul, but we liked the approach presented by Istio (backed by Google, etc) which works really well with Containers (Kubernetes) and you get the support for canary releases https://istio.io/blog/2017/0.1-canary/